# How to flatten nested observables when converting promise to observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm relatively new to observables and still figuring them out.
I'm struggling a bit with this function that I have.  It converts the promise to an observable ok but it returns a nested observable as a result so I have to call subscribe twice.

**How can I flatten this out to return just one observable?**

Note: I have spend quite a bit of time looking over other stackoverflow questions but haven't quite got an answer or maybe I just haven't got it.
I also tried replacing the switchMap with a mergeMap.

```
 removeItem(id: string) {
  let updatedDefectReports: DefectReport[];
      const userId = this.authService.user.uid;
      return from(firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(tokenData => {
        const token = tokenData;
        return this.defectReports.pipe(
          take(1),
          switchMap(defectReports => {
            updatedDefectReports = defectReports;
            const updatedDefectReportIndex = defectReports.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
            updatedDefectReports.splice(updatedDefectReportIndex, 1);
            return this.http.delete<any>
            (`https://defect-report-1cbe3.firebaseio.com/defect-report/${userId}/${id}.json?auth=${token}`);
          }),
          tap(() => {
            this._defectReports.next(updatedDefectReports);
          })
        );
      }));
    }

onRemoveItem(defectReport: DefectReport, slidingItem: IonItemSliding) {
    this.defectReportService.removeItem(defectReport.id).subscribe(res => {
            res.subscribe(() => {
            }, error => {
              this.notificationService.presentAlert('Problem Removing', 'Unable to remove item');
            });
          });
}
```